# The definition of Hardy space

Tags: functional-analysis, hardy-spaces

The definition of the Hardy space consists functions $u(z)$ that are analytic

a. outside the closed unit disc

or

b. inside the open unit disc

What is the difference between the two definition (in application and purpose)

To a. => if system is causal?

To b. => if system is stable?

Thanks!